# kolmogrov equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

i want to show the existence of weak  solution  $f\in L^{2}((0,T)\times \mathbb R,H^{1}_{v}(\mathbb R))$ to the following equation:$$\partial_{t}f=-v\partial_{x}f+\partial_{vv}f$$ in the sense that  it satisfy :$$\int_{[0,T]\times \mathbb R^{2}}(f(-\partial_{t}\phi-v\partial_{x}\phi) +\partial_{v}f\partial_{v}\phi)dtdxdv=\int_{R^{2}} f_{0}\phi_{0}dxdv$$

for $f_{0}\in L^{2}(\mathbb R^{2})$ and $\forall\phi\in C_{c}^{1}([0,T)\times \mathbb R^{2})$
so i xant to do that using the following theorem:[image]

but im not sure about the bilinear form and spaces which i should take in order to aplly the theorem  ,i take for the bilinear form :$B(f,\phi)= \int_{[0,T]\times \mathbb R^{2}}(f(-\partial_{t}\phi-v\partial_{x}\phi) +\partial_{v}f\partial_{v}\phi)dtdxdv$ and the space $H= L^{2}((0,T)\times \mathbb R,H^{1}_{v}(\mathbb R))$ and $\Phi=\{f\in C_{c}^{2}([0,T)\times \mathbb R^{2})  ;\int_{0}^{T}\|\nabla_{x}f v\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R^{2}}+\|f\|_{H^{1}(\mathbb R^{2}}+\|f_{0}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R^{2})}<\infty\}$ is it correct ?
fi sfunction of 3 variables $t\geq 0$, $x\in \mathbb R$ ,$v\in \mathbb R$ and $H^{1}_{v}(\mathbb R)$ is the usual $H^{1}(\mathbb R)$ only on the variable v